Big $O$ notation (2)
I need to prove that $ 5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right)-1\:=\:O\left(n-\sqrt{n}\right) $. So I need to prove that there are two constants $ c $ and $n_0$ for which $ 5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right)-1\le c\left(n-\sqrt{n}\right) \forall n\ge n_0$. How can I do it?
And what about the following reasoning, do you think it is correct?
$5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right)-1 \le 5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right) $. I know that $ \:\dfrac{5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right)}{n-\sqrt{n}} $ tends to $0$ for sufficiently large $n$, so there surely exists a value $c$ which from that specific value of $n$ will always be larger than $ \:\dfrac{5\sqrt{n}\log \left(n\right)}{n-\sqrt{n}} $. In particular, it suffices to choose the smallest value $(n_0)$ for which it is true that $n>5\sqrt{n}\log\left(n\right)+\sqrt{n}.$

There is an explicit solution $$n_0=100 \Big( W_{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{t}\right)  \Big)^2$$ where $W(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function and $t=10 \sqrt[10]{e}$. Numerically, this gives in the real domain $n_0=1380.09$
